Two disks with the same name
I have 4 total disks, and /dev/sdb & /dev/sdd are showing up with the same name.
Two "mirror" drives with different actual disks:

however the Disk Utility clearly shows /dev/sdb as being "media".

If I go to /mnt, I can clearly see that the media and mirror disks contain different and correct contents, so I think it's just the GNOME app is not configured correctly.

You've not provided your Ubuntu product/release details (software changes over time, so what is displayed is best understood by knowing what release you're using), but I see the MEDIA provided in MOUNT point detail; not an actual name; just the result of where it was mounted (/mnt/media)   unless I'm reading different detail to what you're asking about; the zoomed in picture & lack of release detail means I can only think generically

They possibly have the same label - check with lsblk -o NAME,LABEL,UUID,MOUNTPOINT /dev/sd{b,d}1

Thank you guiverc.  Version: Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS. I found it though... from your post, I figured I missed a name somewhere. It turns out the filesystem name was incorrectly configured.

steeldriver - perfect. Thank you for the command line version of this.

Note that steeldriver implicitly pointed out, disks have a unique uuid, a label you can freely assign, a block device seen by the kernel sdb and sdd and a mountpoint where you find the files, by default /mnt/media

@sleepyhead that sounds like it should be an answer ;)
